# Laravel Queue generating `illuminate:queue:restart` continuously

Tags: laravel, redis, queue, laravel-6

Ive Laravel queue running but on Database connection, here is the config:

```
'database' => [
    'driver' => 'database',
    'connection' => 'mysql',
    'table' => 'jobs',
    'queue' => 'default',
    'retry_after' => 190,
    'block_for' => 0,
]
```

This is how I run it:

```
php artisan queue:work --queue=xyz_queue > storage/logs/queue.log
```

On the redis CLI, this is what is happening every second:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is normal and expected behavior. According to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues#running-the-queue-worker)

> Since queue workers are long-lived processes, they will not pick up changes to your code without being restarted. So, the simplest way to deploy an application using queue workers is to restart the workers during your deployment process. You may gracefully restart all of the workers by issuing the queue:restart command: `php artisan queue:restart`

> This command will instruct all queue workers to gracefully "die" after they finish processing their current job so that no existing jobs are lost.

- What `queue:restart` does is that setting current timestamp to the value of `illuminate:queue:restart` key.
- When the queues are about to be **consumed** by the processes (`php artisan queue:work`) it gets that timestamp value from `illuminate:queue:restart` key and after the job is about to be **completed** it gets the value again from the same key.
- It compares whether the the value before the job is processed is same as the after the job is processed.
- If it is different, then it will **stop** long-lived process.

It is an efficient way(since Redis is super fast for this kind of scenarios) to detect whether the code is changed and should the jobs should be updated for this code change.

The reason it saves the value into the Redis, "most probably" your cache driver is Redis. If you change it to `file` then it will be saving in the file instead and making the get request to that file.

Here are the [related methods](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php#L105);

```
protected function stopIfNecessary(WorkerOptions $options, $lastRestart, $job = null)
{
    if ($this->shouldQuit) {
        $this->stop();
    } elseif ($this->memoryExceeded($options->memory)) {
        $this->stop(12);
    } elseif ($this->queueShouldRestart($lastRestart)) {
        $this->stop();
    } elseif ($options->stopWhenEmpty && is_null($job)) {
        $this->stop();
    }
}

protected function queueShouldRestart($lastRestart)
{
    return $this->getTimestampOfLastQueueRestart() != $lastRestart;
}

protected function getTimestampOfLastQueueRestart()
{
    if ($this->cache) {
        return $this->cache->get('illuminate:queue:restart');
    }
}
```

Comment: so it will check every sec `illuminate:queue:restart` key value in Redis even when there is no job to perform?

Comment: Also, yu said `It is an efficient way to detect whether the code is changed and should the jobs should be updated for this code change`, however the `queue:work` is not supposed to detect any code change. Isnt that the whole point of queue:work as a daemon?

Comment: It may execute more than 1 in a second and multiplied with number of processes. If you have 1000 and there is no `sleep` option set in `queue:work` - then you can see maybe 1000+ in a second.(even a small instance redis can handle 100K commands in a second, this one is harmless) Since they are long running processes, the framework(php maybe) is probably caching the same part of the class for performance. They are trying to detect code change while while they are "processing" the job -it is a good way i think. No need to signal manually to warn framework about "i changed the code". @RaheelHasan

Comment: wow, 1000+ per sec?! im glad you told me, ive now set it to a `--delay=30` which is enough for my project!

Comment: @RaheelHasan 1000+ may depend on number of processes and how many instances are connected and what is the sleep etc but it won't be less. As you said, if it is fine for your business rules then totally fine. Glad it helped.

Comment: edit, I meant `--sleep=30`..
Also whats the difference between `--sleep` switch and `block_for` option? I cant make up the difference as both seems to do same thing

Comment: @RaheelHasan i never used/need `block_for` but it is only "redis-available" option since it uses `BLPOP` command . https://redis.io/commands/blpop